# What is metaphysics?

Tags: mantras

There seems to be deeper meaning to the lines in Vedas and Upanishads. I've only listened to some spiritual speakers talk about it. I just wanted to make it seem understandable in terms of metaphysics.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The purpose of science and metaphysics cannot be enjoined, as scope of metaphysics transcends what is  corporeal , unlike science which would demand an empirical evidence to accept any truth.Metaphysics is a broadspectrum analysis (like on one's own real nature , causes of creation),not limited to quantitative physics, furthermore is esoteric , thereby cannot be confined in the realm of science.although both are useful to humanity.Certain aspects that are common may be integrated , to gain the best of both the worlds

Comment: This is far too broad, in fact, it is not even a question, merely a request for wide-ranging information on a vast topic. Please ask a specific question.